# In my webapplication i got error->getting error 503 service unavailable

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, reset

## error 503 service unavailable

I deply asp.net webapplication.
it run well but 2-3 days i get problem i get error **error 503 service unavailable** .
I reset the iis then problem is solve but not resolved permanently.
i have very tired with this problem. It happen in a day 4-5 times.
what is the issue that i have to reset server 4-5 time in day.

Comment: Have you changed anything in the code or server configuration? If not then have you checked for Hardware problems (faulty memory, harddrive, etc.)?

Comment: i didn't any change. and harddrive and memory is ok

Comment: see~ [http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2006/Dec/04/503-Service-Unavailable-in-IIS-7-watch-those-Application-Pools](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2006/Dec/04/503-Service-Unavailable-in-IIS-7-watch-those-Application-Pools)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you have a very bad code line inside your web, that crash your iis, or you **left open handles** and soon or later the iis can not handle that.

For example, this code crash your iis.

```
public string Text
{
   get {return Text;}
   set {Text = value;}
}
```

or

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
  // call by mistake the OnInit and make close loop
  base.OnInit(e);
}
```

or

```
Responce.Redirect("samepage.aspx");
```

or screenscraping the same page.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are not close the connection, check your connections.

you can wrap a SQLConnection in a Using.

"The following example creates a SqlConnection, opens it, displays some of its properties. The connection is automatically closed at the end of the using block."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.close.aspx